# How to set Protocol for a ServletRequest using a Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a a filter like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);
        String host = requestWrapper.getHeader("Host");
        String _protocol = requestWrapper.getProtocol(); // e.g. HTTP/1.1
        if(host == null || host.isEmpty()) {
            host = "127.0.0.1:8080";
        }
        System.out.println("====================================================");
        System.out.println("Updating Host: " + host);
        System.out.println("====================================================");
        requestWrapper.addHeader("Host", host);
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response); // Goes to default servlet.
    }
```

And I want to know if it is possible to modify the protocol (`_protocol`) of a `ServletRequest` inside a filter?

Comment: What is your intent behind changing the protocol? That value should reflect the *actual* value of the protocol for the request the filter is intercepting.

Comment: Since your wrapper can override the `getProtocol()` method and return whatever you want, the answer is: *Yes*. Did you even try? You know, do a bit of **research**? --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Andreas the downvote is quite exaggerated, the getProtocol is an interface method thus, access to the "_protocol" field is not inherently visible that is why I asked.

Comment: @JustinAlbano because Capedwarf (a Google App engine compatible server) is having issue with passing down the protocol to Restlet so I am creating a filter to circumvent the bug.

Comment: @xybrek You modify the `ServletRequest` by wrapping it and overriding the methods whose return values you need to change, **exactly** like you're already doing for the header values. To change a header, you override the `getHeader()` method of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. To change the protocol, you override the `getProtocol()` method of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. It's exactly the same, they are both interface methods. Or is it that you failed to understand what `HeaderMapRequestWrapper` is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and override the `getProtocol`. So long as any of the affected code only uses the `getProtocol` method to obtain the protocol (rather than using the internal value of the protocol), then you can substitute your `ProtocolFixRequest` anywhere the original `HttpServletRequest` was expected. For example:

```
public class ProtocolFixRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final String fixedProtocol;

    public ProtocolFixRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol) {
        super(request);
        fixedProtocol = protocol;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProtocol() {
        return fixedProtocol;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
HttpServletRequest fixedRequest = new ProtocolFixRequest(originalRequest, "myProtocol");
chain.doFilter(fixedRequest, response);
```